# Port forwarding wont work on ZTE MF286D in local network

Tags: linux, networking, router, port-forwarding, linux-server

I am setting up server for own applications and have a problem with port forwarding.

I wanted to expose the server to the internet via the router, but port forwarding doesn't work. My current configuration looks like this:

[image]

Currently, I'm using ZTE MF286D router with static addresses, 192.168.0.14 on WAN and 192.168.2.1 on LAN. It uses the original firmware

On the server, I have installed Ubuntu and I'm running Apache and SSH, both with open ports in UFW.

As WAN client, I use Windows 10.

I tried forwarding port 80/TCP to 192.168.2.2, but it hasn't worked out - Nmap reports no open ports and connection both via browser and ssh fails.

Then I tried opening 192.168.2.2 to DMZ - yet no results.
I don't know what I did wrong! Problems with ISP are (afaik) not possible in this configuration.

I have also tried this with D-Link DIR-635 with almost the same effects. Is it possible that both are busted the same way or am I missing something?

---

Nmap returns

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.14
Host is up (0.00s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.0.14 are in ignored states.
Not shown: 1000 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
MAC Address: [redacted] (zte)
```

I haven't found a way to allow ping requests to ZTE. When pinging 192.168.2.1 from the host requests time out.

---

Here's the port forwarding screen:

[image: Port forwarding options]

---

Result of `nmap -p 22,80 192.168.2.2` from 192.168.0.1

```
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.43 seconds
```

Tried again with `-Pn`

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.2
Host is up.

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh
80/tcp filtered http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 20.03 seconds
```

When I connect on the LAN side, as 192.168.2.3 `nmap -p 22,80 192.168.2.2` results in:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.2
Host is up (0.0023s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
80/tcp open  http
MAC Address: [redacted] (Dell)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 16.94 seconds
```

---

Configs:

UFW `sudo ufw status`

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Samba                      ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
25665                      ALLOW       Anywhere
25565                      ALLOW       Anywhere
Samba (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25665 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25565 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Important router screens:
[Firewall settings menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvv0k.png)
[LAN config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNVjq.png)
[WAN config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj0vI.png)

Netplan config:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.254/24
        - 192.168.2.2/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.2.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.2.1, 192.168.0.14, 192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8, 217.113.224.36, 217.113.224.134]
  version: 2
```

sshd_config:

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
PermitRootLogin yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
PasswordAuthentication yes
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp  /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

---

Tried running docker image on port 3000: `docker run -d -p 3000:3000`. I opened port in UFW, forwarded port in router config, without success.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                 PORTS
   NAMES
15f9c323ad30   ghcr.io/saviusz/melon-server:dev   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   34 minutes ago   Up 34 minutes          0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp   Melon-Server-dev
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151155/discussion-on-question-by-savi-port-forwarding-wont-work-on-zte-mf286d-in-local); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update after additional information has been added to the question:**

Remove the `192.168.0.254/24` from the `enp0s25` interface.

In regards to your question in the comments why this breaks your network, in layman's terms: It makes any address in the `192.168.0.0/24` range part of the LAN network. This means that any data going (back) to any address within `192.168.0.0/24` does not go through the default gateway anymore and thus won't be routed anymore. It sort of stays within the LAN where it doesn't have a destination.

If you want to understand what is actually going on, you need to read up on how IP addressing works in detail. There are plenty of books or online tutorials and videos on YouTube (pretty much basic/fundamental network knowledge). The problem occurs on layer 2 with the encapsulation, instead of using the default gateway's MAC address, it tries to find the IP's MAC address on the LAN (via ARP request), which doesn't exist on the LAN and the packet/frame gets dropped.

**Original answer:**

Your "router" or better the ZTE MF286D device (which is actually an all-in-one device, containing a router, switch, AP, etc.) is probably not correctly configured.

You can NOT use the WAN and the LAN1 port at the same time, since it is physically the same port:

[image]

In the default mode, the WAN comes from the mobile SIM card. If you want to use the WAN port you need to set it to "Cable Broadband Mode", and use LAN 2 to 4 for your LAN network.

The port forward setup should be fine, so I expect the problem to be somewhere else. The only thing you can try is to use a different port for HTTP/HTTPS, some routers use the default port for remote setup over the WAN port (and won't forward on that port).

Be aware that in the standard setup NAT and DHCP will be most likely enabled in the ZTE. I don't know if there are any firewall settings on the ZTE device, I couldn't locate any user guides just the quick setup guide, which gives no detailed information about the setup options.

Could be a UFW misconfiguration as well (e.g. different rules for LAN and WAN). You will need to be more specific in your question. You should post any related setup pages and the setup pages of the devices and servers (ZTE WAN configuration, LAN configuration, NAT, UFW configuration etc.) if you want the community to help you with the troubleshooting. Don't just summarize your setup in words, please show it with screenshots etc.

Comment: You're correct, I actually use LAN 2, just misspelled creating diagram. And "Cable Broadband Mode" set as well - I've assumed it'll be obvious. I'll try changing port configuration later

Comment: @Savi you are correct, its obvious, but a lot of times that's where the problems lie. Please correct your answer and let us know. Please also show the server (network) configuration for the servers you are trying to connect to (SSH etc.).